# Chunks/Page<>.js not loading in a Sitecore 10.2 SSG + NextJS after NextJs upgrade

Tags: nextjs

I am looking for some guidance around upgrading NextJs and ReactJs on the with Sitecore 10.2. Please find below the details for the implemetation:

1. Sitecore 10.2 with "Sitecore Headless ver 20.0.2" and
   "sitecore-jss-cli ver as 20.1.3"
2. NextJs upgraded from 12.2.4 to 13.4.17
3. ReactJs upgraded from 17.0.2 to 18.2.0
4. Using Static Site Generation in the default path file `[[...path]].tsx`

However now we are getting an issue of the respective `_next/chunks/page<>.js` not loading for any of the site URLs. We are getting the issue even if we don't add any component on the page except for the JSS layout.

Could anyone let me know where I am going wrong or anything additional that I need to configure to fix this issue? Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: You might have already gone through the upgrade guide for [Next 12 to 13](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-13) and [React 17 to 18](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide). Check if you have missed something, also if you can share the `next build` logs that might help to understand what's happening.